# Access denied running sn.exe on Windows 7

Tags: .net

I'm trying to build / sign an assembly on a Windows 7 machine and I get the following exception:

```
x:\> SN -q -Vr "x:\someassembly.dll"
Failed to open registry key -- Access is denied.
```

I've found the following thread that appears to be the same problem, and it mentions that he fixed it by changing permissions on a registry key, however it doesnt mention which registry key.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsbuild/thread/e84e015b-41c8-4170-8686-2474832fcd28

Has anyone encountered this before?

Comment: I had an issue similar to this... try this...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11887/sn-exe-fails-with-access-denied-error-message

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I identified the key in question using [Process Mon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx), which lists the following:

```
sn.exe
RegCreateKey
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\StrongName
ACCESS DENIED
Desired Access: Maximum Allowed
```

Giving write access for the current user to the following key fixed this problem

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft
```

Note that giving write access to the root HKLM node **didnt** fix my problem (apparently permissions of folders in the registry aren't recursive?)

Comment: I was able to execute sn.exe from an elevated console, but another step in my build process could not be executed from an elevated prompt.  I tried Justin's suggestion, but found that that didn't work.  I then used [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see which keys sn was trying to write to and it turned out to be: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\StrongName.  Once I gave my account full access to that key it worked.

Comment: Granting a regular user write access to the system strong name metadata - even more so, to the entire system-critical `Microsoft` key - is a security compromise. You're calling `-Vr` (register an assembly for strong name validation skip) which indeed is a privileged operation.

Comment: In my case, I used elevated permissions. But, I call the program using Powershell.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the case you may use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to see which registry key sn.exe is trying to access. This is not really programming related though.

Answer (score 0):

Using `-Vr` with `sn.exe` is considered a potential security risk, as it disables signature validation. That's why you cannot run `sn.exe -Vr` from an unprivileged command prompt.

Open an elevated command prompt (with administrative privileges) before trying to execute `sn.exe -Vr`.

By the way, using `-Vr` registers a verification entry (which indicates that the specified assembly or assemblies should not be verified) and should only be used temporarily while executing instrumented binaries (which have not been signed after instrumentation).

Don't forget to use `-Vu` to unregister the entry when you are done.

Answer (score 0):

As others and myself have pointed out, `-Vr` (register an assembly for strong name validation skip, system-wide) is indeed a privileged operation, and the "access denied" you get is legitimate.

According to [Sn.exe (Strong Name Tool) - MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/k5b5tt23(v=vs.110).aspx), you can add a user name to specify the user to disable the check for. This shouldn't require administrative privileges:

```
sn -Vr <Assembly> %USERNAME%
```