# Profiling a signed WinForm dll in VS2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio, performance, profiling

I have a Winforms solution `MySolution.exe` having inside a `MyControl.dll` that I want to profile.

When I try to run the performance profiling tool in VS 2010 on it it gives me the following warning

> *MyControl.dll* is signed and
>   instrumenting it will invalidate its
>   signature. If you proceed without a
>   post-instrument event to re-sign the
>   binary it may not load correctly.

after that the same warning with the *`MySolution.exe`*`is signed...`

Now, if I choose the option to continue without re-signing the profiling starts solution crashes and nothing finally happens.

I saw some [similar solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711484/vs-2010-profiling-problem-with-signed-assemblies), but dind't understand how to apply the provided solution in a WinForm solution.

Say, I have `MySolution.exe` and the dll to profile is `MyControl.dll`... both, the solution and the project are signed with a key `MyKey.snk`

Answer (score 0):

As you point out the answer is in the question you have highlighted.

What you need to do is resign the 'modified' assembly using a post build step. You will find the place to add this under Build Events when you look at the Properties of the project.

**sn -R < path to assembly > < path to key >**

Alternatively you could disable signature verification (as also suggested) completely using

**sn -Vr ***

If the latter works this would be simpler and then you just need to remember to re-enable signature verification once you have finished profiling.

**sn -Vx**