# How can I profile Signed Assemblies with VS 2012

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, profiler, instrumentation

This is basically the same as [How can I profile Signed Assemblies with VS 2010 or VS 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711484/how-can-i-profile-signed-assemblies-with-vs-2010-or-vs-2013), but after having run

```
sn -Vr *
```

successfully (in an elevated cmd.exe), as suggested by the [answer with the most votes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3880152/709537).

I still get this dialog for every strong named dll selected for instrumentation

> x.dll is signed and instrumenting it will invalidate its signature. If you proceed without a post-instrument event to re-sign the binary it may not load correctly.

and no matter if I click "yes" or "no", VS won't profile. So how can I instrument-profile?