# Is it possible to gather code coverage data without the code coverage tool being the entry point?

Tags: c#, .net, automated-tests, code-coverage

I am trying to gather code coverage information from my test bed.

The majority of code coverage tools I have considered using so far all operate by being the entry point to your software; typically you pass a command line argument or executable path to the code coverage tool and it runs your program, gathering code coverage data while it is running.

Unfortunately, I am in a situation where my testing solution starts and stops my program for each test.  This means that traditional code coverage isn't going to work.

Is there a way to passively monitor an executable and related DLLs for code coverage while it is being run by other processes?

Please note that I am not asking for specific software recommendations.  I just want to know if the type of code coverage gathering that I need is possible, and if so, what it is called so I can do further research on my own.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [vsperfcmd](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/vsperfcmd) and [vsinstr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/vsinstr).

You use `vsinstr` to instrument the binaries and then start and stop the `vsperfcmd` to indicate the start and stop of your coverage period.

So you can do:

```
vsinstr -coverage $(pathToDLL1)
vsinstr -coverage $(pathToDLL2)
vsinstr -coverage $(pathToDLL3)
vsperfcmd -start:coverage -output:SomePath\ManualCoverage.coverage
// DO YOUR TESTING HERE
vsperfcmd -shutdown
```

On VS 2015, you can look in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools\x64` for both binaries.

Comment: I'd looked at these before.  I wasn't quite sure if they worked the way I thought they did.  I'll do some testing with these.

Comment: Actually, this doesn't look like it's going to work.  Using vsinstr on the program prevents the program from running.  I guess it's a signing issue.

Comment: Try this if you are signing the assemblies: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2711484/how-can-i-profile-signed-assemblies-with-vs-2010-or-vs-2013